# How to use "offers" for small business that offers childcare services?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

Using Google Rich Snippet to present my business as `ChildCare` ("A Childcare center.") how I can point to the services (programs) which I am offering in the facility as `Offer` in `itemprop="offers"`?

For example I am offering 3 services (programs) in the childcare like programs for "Infant, Toddlers, and Preschoolers". How I can use the offer to point these services and their options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to model the services as [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer), you can use the [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) property from `ChildCare`:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ChildCare">

  <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="name">For Infants</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="name">For Toddlers</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="name">For Preschoolers</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you want to model the services as [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service), you can use the [`provider`](http://schema.org/provider) property from `Service`:

```html
<!-- because itemref gets used, this element may not be a child of another Microdata item -->
<div itemprop="provider" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ChildCare" id="the-childcare-business">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service" itemref="the-childcare-business">
  <span itemprop="name serviceType">Childcare for Infants</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service" itemref="the-childcare-business">
  <span itemprop="name serviceType">Childcare for Toddlers</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service" itemref="the-childcare-business">
  <span itemprop="name serviceType">Childcare for Preschoolers</span>
</div>
```

The main difference is that you may provide a price ([`price`](http://schema.org/price)/[`priceCurrency`](http://schema.org/priceCurrency)) for an `Offer`, but not for a `Service`.

You could of course also use both types.

Comment: Note that this answers it from the perspective of Schema.org. I don’t know if Google offers a Rich Snippet for either of those.